# Is there a standard ros 3x3 matrix message

Tags: matrix, ros

Is there a standardized message type for sending a 3x3 rotation matrix's over ros?

Ideally what I would like would be something like this.

```
#rotation.msg

Header header
float64[9]  R
```

But before I make a custom message I would like to know if something similar to this already exists? I couldn't find anything, but it seems odd that there isn't a 3x3 matrix type.

Comment: I don't know of any standard message providing a 3x3 matrix. But I know that rotations are usually represented as quaternions (x, y, z, w) which is more compact and therefore there is no need for a 3x3 matrix. You can find the Quaternion.msg in geometry_msgs.

Comment: @ave: I think, you should post this as an answer so that it can be accepted and the questions does not stay unanswered.

Comment: One thing to add for completeness: There is `std_msgs/Float64MultiArray` which probably could be used, but I think it is overkill for a fixed size 3x3 matrix. Using Quaternions is the way to go here.

Comment: Yes, i left Float64MultiArray intentionally unmentioned. It's indeed an overkill and too complicated to use for a simple case like this. I'd rather create a new float64[9] message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any standard message providing a 3x3 matrix. But I know that rotations are usually represented as quaternions (x, y, z, w) which is more compact and therefore there is no need for a 3x3 matrix. You can find the Quaternion.msg in geometry_msgs.